# Subjunctive Third-person singular

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis, futuro

I do not understand why in Spanish the following sentence makes sense

> Cuando Jaime cumpla 50 años, vamos a darle una fiesta.

but this does not?

> Cuando Jaime  cumpliere 50 años, vamos a darle una fiesta

Since we are referring to Jamie, don't we use the future tense of el/ella instead of the present tense of yo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a somewhat advanced topic in Spanish, and a not so easy one.

A brief explanation is:

- **Cumpla** is the present tense of subjunctive mood of the verb *cumplir* for **both** the first and third persons singular. [Check its conjugation with RAE.](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=ItaXfmTPfVcRjyKa0c37)
- When you use the conjunction **cuando** to join both the main and the subordinated sentence, you are faced with two situations:

  1. When dealing with *non real facts*, i.e. facts that haven't actually or yet happened, you use the **subjunctive mood**:

     - You use it in the present of subjunctive for future hypothetical events.

       > **Vamos a** darle una fiesta **cuando** Jaime **cumpla** 50 años.
       >   Le **haremos** una fiesta **cuando** Jaime **cumpla** 50 años.
       >   **Iremos** al concierto de Iron Maiden **cuando** **vuelvan** a Chile.
     - You use it in preterite of subjunctive for past events that didn't happen, events you want to express that you expected to happen.

       > **Íbamos a** darle una fiesta **cuando** Jaime **cumpliese** 50 años.
       >   **Queríamos** saludar a nuestros amigos **cuando** **visitaran** nuestra ciudad.
     - You never use future of subjunctive in these cases in present day Spanish. @guifa gives good information about this fact in his own answer.
     - There is no sense using **cuando** for present situations, that is the reason for only past (using preterite of subjunctive) and future (using present of subjunctive).
  2. When dealing with *real facts*, i.e. facts that actually happened, you use the **indicative mood**:

     - This situation can only be used with past events (because you cannot speak about facts that actually happened in the future).

       > **Teníamos** la fiesta lista **cuando** Jaime **llegó** a casa.
       >   **Recorrimos** todo el centro de la ciudad **cuando** **visitamos** París.

Here, I've just written your examples in the "canonical" order: first the main sentence, then the subordinated one. This **is not** the only right order, you can write it just as you did in your question. This is another advantage of having a subjunctive mood differentiated from the indicative: you can easily recognize the subordinated sentence from the main one.

---

A more syntactical summary:

Besides some marginal cases, we can summarize these examples with the following rules:

1. Hypothetical facts:

   - For hypothetical future events:

     - **Main sentence**: future of indicative (or "proximal future" of indicative, using **ir a** with an infinitive.
     - **Subordinated sentence**: present of subjunctive.
   - For hypothetical past events:

     - **Main sentence**: imperfect (a.k.a. indefinite).
     - **Subordinated sentence**: preterite of subjunctive.
2. Real facts:

   - For past events, you can use both forms of preterite of indicative. Which one to use depends on the specific differences we have with these two forms.

     - **Main sentence**: any form of preterite of indicative.
     - **Subordinated sentence**: any form of preterite of indicative.

Comment: thanks, can you link me to the source(if it is easily avaiable) of where the rules are for conjunction cuando

Comment: I've just expanded my answer to cover a missing point (the subjunctive is not the only mood used with `cuando`). Regarding the sources, I am still searching for a brief one to publish here. All I know about these facts I studied from books.

Comment: Why is "cuando cumpla 50" not real?.  If he doesn't die eventually he will be 50.

Comment: It is not real in the sense it hasn't happened yet. _Maybe_ it happen some day. You have used: *If he doesn't die ...*, using an *if*, so there is a doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your second sentence *made* sense, but it doesn't make sense.  <sub>(get? tense joke...)</sub>

Old Spanish allowed the use of future subjunctive in this situation just like modern Portuguese and Galician do.  Compare:

- Cuando **tuviere** más dinero, comprarélo.  <sub>(castellano áurico)</sub>
- Quando **tiver** mais dinheiro, comprá-lo-ei.  <sub>(português moderno)</sub>
- Cando **tiver** mais diñeiro, compraréio.  <sub>(galego moderno)</sub>

But modern Spanish does not.  Instead, the present subjunctive is used.

- Cuando **tenga** más dinero, lo compraré. <sub>(castellano moderno)</sub>

It is technically permissible to use future subjunctive in modern Spanish, but no one actually uses it in spoken language, and only a very small number of people would use it regularly in writing.  It's really only used in legal texts where the small distinction made between present and future subjunctive is quite important (*el que mate al rey* vs. *el que matare al rey* being the standard example given).  Also, in my experience, it's almost exclusively used alongside the simple future, rather than the periphrastic, so if you did want to use it, the better way would be:

- Cuando Jaime **cumpliere** 50 años, le **daremos** una fiesta. <sub>(castellano moderno requeteformal)</sub>

But, this also has the additional implication that Jaime may or may not actually reach his 50th birthday.  If you use the present subjunctive, we take it as a given that he will indeed reach his 50th birthday.  (also, if we're being that incredible formal, we might as well also use an enclitic pronoun with *darémosle*).